# RSpec and Sunspot: Errno::ECONNREFUSED. How is this solved?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, rspec, sunspot

I am relatively new to Rails. I have a model Micropost, and it has an attribute "content" that I validate presence for. This model is also searchable using sunspot

```
class Micropost < ActiveRecord::Base

  searchable do
    text :content, boost: 5
    text :tag_list, boost: 2
    text :details
  end

  validates :content, presence: true
end
```

I am trying to run a simple rspec test in my micropost_sepc.rb

```
   let(:valid_attributes) {
          {content: "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry."}
     }

    context "validations" do
     let(:micropost) { Micropost.new(valid_attributes) }

     before do
       Micropost.create(valid_attributes)
     end

     it "requires content" do
       expect(micropost).to validate_presence_of(:content)
      end
    end
```

But I am getting this error

```
   1) Micropost validations requires content
      Failure/Error: Micropost.create(valid_attributes)
      Errno::ECONNREFUSED:
      Connection refused
```

Which I am assuming is in someway related to sunspot. I really have no clue how to approach this problem - obviously there must be a way around this.

I'd be really grateful for some guidance (point in the right direction at least)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running the solr server in test mode like this:

```
bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:start RAILS_ENV=test
```